On Ubuntu 24.04, Remmina closes while connecting to any server as RDP
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, When I try to connect with SFTP or SSH it is connecting but if I try to connect with RDP, It closes automatically.
I also have another issue, While saving the data for SSH, I couldn't enter all the data at once and save it, if I give all the data at once it just closes automatically. First I need to save with a name, then edit the saved record add the server, and then save it again, again editing to enter other data likewise it goes on

For the first problem: What happens if you try to connect from the command line?  The RDP port is TCP/3389.  Use telnet to try connecting to it: telnet yourHostIP 3389.  You may need to install the telnet client if you don't have it: apt install telnet.

@kos I think he means "While saving the [Remmina entry] for SSH, ...".  Possibly another Remmina bug.

@klode Makes sense, thanks for dissecting it, I thought they were talking about something else entirely :|

I removed my "I have this too" comment because in fact I now remember I had while this trying to connect to another machine that turned to be misconfigured and would always deny connection. So it may be that the crash happens only when the server denies the connection. I would suggest trying with a known-to-be-working server first.

Check this solution:
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt update
sudo apt install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret

This helped me
